# Why run Quart app with Hypercorn / isn't it automatic?

Tags: server, python-asyncio, python-3.7, quart, hypercorn

If you inspect the *Quart* library, `app.run()` just establishes some config and then uses `asyncio.run(serve(self, config))`, where serve comes from `from hypercorn.asyncio import serve`.

So even if you run a *Quart* app via `python myapp.py`, isn't it already using a *Hypercorn* server?

In particular, what's the difference between this and running via `hypercorn myapp:app`?

https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/deployment.html

> > It is not recommended to run Quart directly (via run()) in production. Instead it is recommended that Quart be run using Hypercorn or an alternative ASGI server. **Hypercorn is installed with Quart and is used to serve requests by default (e.g. with run())**.

So it sounds like, even though *Hypercorn* is used to serve requests by default with `run()`, it is not recommended to use `run()`?  Is anyone else confused?

Comment: Link in the question is dead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So even if you run a Quart app via python myapp.py, isn't it already using a Hypercorn server?

Yep.

> In particular, what's the difference between this and running via hypercorn myapp:app?

I want to reserve the `run` method for development so that it can by default make decisions that are beneficial for development, but bad for production. An example at the moment is that the `run` method uses the reloader (reloads the app whenever the code changes) by default, which is great when developing but a performance issue in production. Another example is that the `run` method will not use multiple workers, which again leads to worse performance in production.

(I am the Quart author)

Comment: So performance aside, does it affect security at all? For example if I were to deploy an app that only gets very few requests, would it matter?

Comment: Yes, the debug mode will reveal more about your local setup, including possibly values of sensitive variables, on error (the traceback error page).